# No way to disable search in Antd 3.x Select component(even when showSearch prop is set to false)

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, antd

I am using [Select component](https://3x.ant.design/components/select/) from Antd 3.x library with mode="multiple" and other options as shown in codesandbox link below. The Search is not disabled even when setting showSearch={false}

Now, I can't upgrade to Antd 4.x. The issue is when I use [Axe Accessibility tool](https://www.deque.com/axe/) on my web app, it complains about an extra "Input" in my Select, which doesn't have aria-label set. If I manually set it in chrome console, all is fine

- Is there a way to work around this situation either by removing search field(not sure how?) or someway to set the aria-lable of the input to something like aria-lable="search"?

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-fast-d1ljj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/index.js)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filterOption` to control your option list.

In my case, my options's value is a list of accounts, which will change every times I input keyword. Option's value is `account.id` and label is `account.name`.

- `filterOption`, set it `() => true` (that means, all of options are OK).
- `onSearch`, I call API to request new list of accounts, which meet with my keyword.

But in your case, I think, set `filterOption` to `() => true` will solve your problem.

Hope you solve with my solution!

Comment: Thanks for trying. I still see the searchBar in AxeTool